# AsyncPipe used for ngIf and Passing Data

Tags: angular, observable, async-pipe

Is it bad practice to use AsyncPipe in multiple bindings? I have a component that takes an observable and I am using it as a data input along with *ngIf like so

```
<sample-component 
   ngIf="sampleObs$ | async"
   [data] = "sampleObs$ | async"
></sample-component>
```

It works as expected, I was just wondering if this was an okay practice as I am new to Angular

Comment: It depends on what `sampleObs$` is doing when you call it. If it makes an http request per call, then yes. If it returns a cached value that is refreshed elsewhere, then no. What is `sampleObs$` in your case?

Comment: @KurtHamilton sambleObs is just an array of data that is returned from an http request that is called OnInit of a parent component

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using async as

```
ngIf="sampleObs$ | async as sampleObs"
```

Then the next call you just use sampleObs.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't seem to assing sambleObs within the component data binding. It always stayed as undefined

Comment: Put the ng-if in an ng-container before the component